# ''Save up to 50% of installation time'' vs. ''Save up to 50% on installation time''?

Tags: word-usage

> "Save up to 50% **of** installation time" vs. "Save up to 50% **on** installation time"

Using *of* seems incorrect to me. If you wanted to use *of*, it should be followed by 'your' or indeed leave out *of* altogether.

Comment: _Cut installation time by up to 50%_ (point is, there is often more than one grammatical way to say something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some additional context, but I would say "on" is correct. If we say "save 50% **of** something", then it means that we keep 50% of that "something". If we say "save 50% **on** something", then it means that we don't have to pay 50% of the usual amount for that "something".

For example:

- I saved 50% *of* the money I earned for a rainy day. (I kept half of what I earned.)
- I saved 50% *of* my notes from college. (I didn't throw away half my notes.)
- I saved 50% *on* car insurance. (What I paid for car insurance was half of what I usually would have.)

In this case, because "time" isn't something we can keep somewhere in our house, it's almost certainly "on", meaning that "you can get *this thing* up to 50%  faster".

Comment: Interesting, though, how we use _of_ with "the time" quite often: *50% of the time, we lose the coin toss*.

Comment: True. I think it probably comes from "50% of the times" meaning "50% of the trials" or total possible outcomes. I think we've just lost the 's' over time, or perhaps the 's' wasn't required when the expression originated.